# Reference a function with a general expression

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I want to be able to reference a particuler function with a general expression and a variable within another function, like the following:

```
Function simpletest()
i = 1
simpletest = doom"i"
End Function

Function doom1()
doom1 = success
End Function
```

Is this possible in VBA, If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: Look into `Application.Run`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
Sub SimpleTest()
    i = 1
    Application.Run "doom" & i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Function simpletest()
Dim function_name as String 
   function_name = "doom" 
   i = 1
   function_name = function_name & CStr(i)
   Application.Run function_name 
End Sub 

Function doom1()
doom1 = success
End Function
```

Let me know if something has to be changed

Answer (score 1):

### Function by Expression

```
Option Explicit

Function SimpleTest(FName As String, FSuffix As String) As String
    SimpleTest = FName & FSuffix
End Function

Function Doom1() As String
    Doom1 = "Success in Doom1"
End Function

Function Doom2() As String
    Doom2 = "Success in Doom2"
End Function

Sub test()

    Const cTitle As String = "Doom"
    Dim i As Long

    ' Write the results to the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G).
    For i = 1 To 2
        Debug.Print Application.Run(SimpleTest(cTitle, CStr(i)))
    Next

End Sub
```